# Firebase functions : Cannot set property config of #<Object> which has only a getter

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

Firebase functions was working fine 
I updated to latest firebase-tools 
Now running into this error issue when running firebase serve.

```
[debug] [2020-05-28T20:37:11.387Z] [runtime-status] [93658] Error in handleMessage:  => TypeError: Cannot set property config of #<Object> which has only a getter: TypeError: Cannot set property config of #<Object> which has only a getter
    at {....}/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:455:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled ({....}/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:5:58)
[warn] ⚠  functions: Cannot set property config of #<Object> which has only a getter {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Cannot set property config of #<Object> which has only a getter"}}
[warn] ⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error. {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error."}}
```

Comment: If you have a bug report, file it on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Turns out this was submitted and fixed about the same time that I posted it here. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2301 Fix should be available in 8.4.1 soon.

Comment: I got this error trying to do `orderBy = ("title", "desc")` instead of `orderBy("title", "desc")`. Stupid me.

Answer (score 28):

I just got the same error when trying to `firebase serve`. The fix for me was simply to update my firebase-tools to the latest version with `npm install -g firebase-tools`. The newest update appears to have solved this particular problem.

edit: The fix was released in version 8.4.1 of firebase-tools

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this was submitted and fixed about the same time that I posted it here: [GitHub - firebase-tools - Cannot set property config of # which has only a getter #2301](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2301)

Fix should be available in 8.4.1 soon.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check you **firebase-debug.log** for the firebase-tools version. The bug was fixed in **firebase-tools: 8.4.1**.

   `[debug] [2020-10-08T09:42:11.364Z] CLI Version:   8.8.1`
2. **Upgrade** the global firebase cli

   `npm i -g firebase-cli@8.12.0`
3. Check your package.json for the firebase-cli version and if lower than 8.4.1 **upgrade** it as well.

   `npm i firebase-cli@8.12.0`
4. Run **firebase emulators:start** and check again the **firebase-debug.log** for the cli version. It should be higher then **8.4.1**

   `[debug] [2020-10-08T09:42:11.364Z] CLI Version:   8.8.1`

Answer (score 1):

Just update firebase-functions to 3.6.0

With NPM: `npm i firebase-functions@3.6.0`

With yarn: `yarn add firebase-functions@3.6.0`

Comment: Updating firebase-functions went well for me, thanks!